# Find items, related to article by name

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I have an article (title, body) stored in mysql, and i have about 1M rows (name) stored in mysql and indexed with elasticsearch. How can i find rows, which names are found (100% match of name) in article title or body? Thanks for any suggetions.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service**

Comment: But I thing the question is clear and have clear answers !

Answer (score 1):

You can use LOCATE Function :

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.Name FROM name_table N, article_table A
WHERE ((LOCATE(N.Name, A.Title) > 0) OR (LOCATE(N.Name, A.Body) > 0));
```

or with join on condition :

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.Name FROM name_table N JOIN article_table A
ON ((LOCATE(N.Name, A.Title) > 0) OR (LOCATE(N.Name, A.Body) > 0));
```

The Locate function returns > 0 for inputs like this : locate('oo', 'Mahmood'),
to solve this problem , you can concatenate your Name with Spaces (or ',')

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.Name FROM name_table N JOIN article_table A
ON ((LOCATE(Concat(' ', N.Name, ' '), A.Title) > 0)
OR (LOCATE(Concat(' ', N.Name, ' '), A.Body) > 0));
```

you can add other Concatenates in the condition